# Unity camera flicks across screen, first person

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I am new to UNITY I have written some code for a first person camera however sometimes when I am looking around it will flick what way the camera is facing. This is my code

```
public float mouseSensitivity = 200f;
public Transform playerBody;
float yRotation = 0f;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.visible = false;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

    yRotation -= mouseY;
    yRotation = Mathf.Clamp(yRotation, -90f, 90f);
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(yRotation, 0f, 0f);
    playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
}
```

I have a video to show my issue as well https://youtu.be/nMopJzNyYr4 for is the question is not clear.

I have a capsule as my parent it is the players actual body and then my camera is a child to the playerBody ( my capsule )

Comment: please include info about the hierarchy of `transform` and `playerBody`

Comment: I have a capsule as my parent it is the players actual body and then my camera is a child to the playerBody ( my capsule )

Comment: Try it without the `deltaTime` multiplication. `GetAxis` on a mouse axis gives you a difference in mouse position, which is not frame dependent.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359) to give me some reputation points as well as help other people with a similar problem find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it without the `deltaTime` multiplication. `GetAxis` on a mouse axis gives you a difference in mouse position, which should not be multiplied by `deltaTime` or any other time delta unless you are interested in a measurement of [Absement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absement) which you probably are not!!

You are more interested in a distance measurement, so you can just use
`float mouseABC = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ABC") * mouseSensitivity;`.

Alternatively, if you were to want the speed of the mouse movement, you would actually rather **divide** by `time.deltaTime` such as `float mouseHorizontalVelocity = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity / Time.deltaTime;`.