# Camera spins and inputs are inverted

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently creating a 3D platformer game using the Unity game engine and I was following this tutorial series to get some basic player movement: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2d9Wc3Hhi0&list=PLiyfvmtjWC_V_H-VMGGAZi7n5E0gyhc37. After I finished the movement part of the tutorial,  I ran into a problem. Whenever I move my mouse to the rotation thresholds, the camera avoids the threshold and rotates around the y axis. After it spins, the mouse inputs get inverted. Here is my code for the camera controller:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Player
{
    public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Transform target;
        public Transform orientation;
        public Vector3 offset;
        public bool useOffsetValues;
        public float sensitivity;
        public float maxViewAngle = 85;
        public float minViewAngle = -75;
        public bool invertY;

        private void Start()
        {
            if (!useOffsetValues)
            {
                offset = target.position - transform.position;
            }

            orientation.position = target.position;
            orientation.parent = null;

            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        }

        private void LateUpdate()
        {
            orientation.position = target.position;

            float yaw = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            orientation.Rotate(0, yaw, 0);

            float pitch = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            if (invertY) orientation.Rotate(pitch, 0, 0);
            else orientation.Rotate(-pitch, 0, 0);

            if (orientation.rotation.eulerAngles.x > maxViewAngle && orientation.rotation.eulerAngles.x < 180)
            {
                orientation.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(maxViewAngle, orientation.eulerAngles.y, 0);
            }
            if (orientation.rotation.eulerAngles.x < 360 + minViewAngle && orientation.rotation.eulerAngles.x > 180)
            {
                orientation.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(360 + minViewAngle, orientation.eulerAngles.y, 0);
            }

            float yAngle = orientation.eulerAngles.y;
            float xAngle = orientation.eulerAngles.x;
            Quaternion rot = Quaternion.Euler(xAngle, yAngle, 0);
            transform.position = target.position - (rot * offset);

            if (transform.position.y < target.position.y - 0.5f)
            {
                transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, target.position.y - 0.5f, transform.position.z);
            }

            transform.LookAt(target);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What are you using for `offset`? or if you're using a `useOffsetValues` of true, what value gets assigned to it?

Comment: @Ruzihm I think `offset` shows the position of the camera relative to the player. Because  `useOffsetValues` is false, mine goes to (0, 0, 5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't multiply `GetAxis(mouse_axis_name)` by a delta time. `GetAxis(mouse_axis_name)` returns a distance, which does not mean much when multiplied by a delta time. Just use `float yaw = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity;` and `float pitch = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity;` [to avoid problems caused by changing framerates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64937075/1092820).

Second, instead of comparing euler angle components, it is easier to simply clamp `pitch` to a range which won't cause the rotation to extend out of bounds, using [`Vector3.Angle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html) to calculate angles and [`Mathf.Clamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) to do the clamping.  This accounts for lost information between a conversion from euler angles to the `Transform`'s internal `Quaternion` representation. To help that, set minimum up and down angles. The greater these are, the more constrained the camera is to certain angles.

Third, the offset should be just a distance, in order to avoid it fighting with the clamping for how rotated the camera may be.

Fourth, you can use a `Quaternion localRotation` for the camera's state instead of a whole `Transform`, which does a bunch of extra stuff that you don't even use. Use `Quaternion.Euler(0f, yaw, 0f) * desiredRotation * Quaternion.Euler(pitch, 0f, 0f)` to rotate the quaternion around global up by `yaw` and local right by `pitch` and then `desiredRotation * Vector3.forward` to find the forward the rotation wants to produce.  Use `Quaternion.LookRotation` to intialize it to the rotation that makes the camera look at the target.

Altogether:

```
[SerializeField] Transform target;
[SerializeField] float offset;
[SerializeField] bool useOffsetValues;
[SerializeField] float sensitivity;
[SerializeField] float minUpAngle = 5f;
[SerializeField] float minDownAngle = 5f;
[SerializeField] bool invertY;

Quaternion desiredRotation;

void Start()
{
    Vector3 positionDelta = target.position - transform.position;
    if (!useOffsetValues)
    {
        offset = positionDelta;
    }

    desiredRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(positionDelta);
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    float yaw = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity;
    float pitch = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity;
    if (!invertY) pitch = -pitch;

    float angleForwardUp = Vector3.Angle(desiredRotation * Vector3.forward, Vector3.up);
    float angleForwardDown = 180f - angleForwardUp;

    float pitchMin = minUpAngle - angleForwardUp;
    float pitchMax = angleForwardDown - minDownAngle;

    pitch = Mathf.Clamp(pitch, pitchMin, pitchMax);

    desiredRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, yaw, 0f) * desiredRotation 
            * Quaternion.Euler(pitch, 0f, 0f);

    transform.position = target.position - (desiredRotation
            * Vector3.forward * offset);

    if (transform.position.y < target.position.y - 0.5f)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,
                target.position.y - 0.5f,
                transform.position.z);
    }

    transform.LookAt(target);
}
```

Comment: @WeirdGuy Sorry, I used `target` in places I didn't mean to. After looking closely, I realized that I didn't quite understand the goal of the last bit of code at first.  This should fix your problem. Let me know if anything pops up.

Comment: If I want to use `orientation, how would I do that?

Comment: @WeirdGuy Please describe what you are trying to do with it to avoid an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/405359). This information should be included in the question. The straight answer to your question is `orientation.position = target.position;` and `orientation.rotation = desiredRotation;` but I can't be sure that will actually help you.

Comment: @WeirdGuy Great! Consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359) this answer so that people with a similar problem can find this answer more easily. It also gives me some reputation points ;)